# UNSUPPORTED_APEX_TRIGGER_OPERATION:Apex Task trigger cannot handle batch operations on recurring tasks

Tags: apex

I received the error message

> "UNSUPPORTED_APEX_TRIGGER_OPERATION: Apex Task
>
> trigger cannot handle batch operations on recurring tasks."

Could you please help me find a solution to such error.

Answer (score 2):

I finally received responses back from the premier developer support. The gentleman I worked with had never seen this error and initially thought it was something I coded into the functionality on purpose. After working through various scenarios, we figured out that the functionality and the resulting error is expected behavior.

Here's the line from the Salesforce documentation:

> "A trigger invoked by an insert, delete or update of a recurring event
>   or recurring task results in a runtime error when the trigger is
>   called in bulk from the Force.com API."

I guess there must be some reason for this limitation so I'll have to deal with it until some future release where this is addressed.

This answer is given by greg may this help you out ...

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008xrmIAA